# error in java code for accessing files with swedish characters on linux

Tags: java, unix, file-io, locale, opensuse

I have written the following java code in unix to access a file having Swedish characters in its file name.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"));

String filePath = "/tmp/newöäåå.txt";
System.out.println("File Path" + filePath);

File file = new File(filePath);
try {
    if(file.exists())
        System.out.println("length: " + file.length());
    else{
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("inside exception");
}
```

Output :

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
File Path /tmp/newÃ¶Ã¤Ã¥Ã¥.txt
file not found
```

I have created the the file through unix only. Can you help me understand what must be going wrong?

The operating system is Open SUSE

Comment: What software are you using to edit the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may be in the code itself. **The .java files are not saved in UTF-8 encoding**. Maybe try to read the filename from an external file that is UTF-8 or represent the file name otherwise or simply ensure the .java file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you save you java file in UTF-8 - it will work.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to edit and compiling the code too..and the encoding I have set explicitly to UTF-8 in eclipse.


Then I am transferring this compiled file to Unix and executing it there.


When I am trying to compile this file on unix, i am getting like

NewDemo.java:1:illegal character : \65279

which i believe me is coming for the statement ***String filePath = "/tmp/newöäåå.txt";***

Is some other thing wrong with the environment?

Comment: When compiling try to use javac option: -encoding UTF-8